# Issues with QString and debugging in Qt development

Tags: debugging, qt, qstring

1. I'm using DOM model to generate XML. When I have the DOM tree ready and try to output XML via `return domDocument.toString(4);`, it only gives me the first 255 characters. I've tried with `domDocument.save(QTextStream(&someQString), 4);` too, and get the same result. In contrast, `return domDocument.toByteArray(4);` works fine, but it's cut off to 255 charaters again when I initialize a QString with the QByteArray. Can someone give me a clue what the problem is with QString?
2. I'm developing using VS 2008 with Qt add-in. When debugging, I see many XML DOM objects that have only one member - impl. This makes much trouble for me to debug. How can I see the tree structure instead of this pointer?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) are you sure you have a propertly formatted document in input?

Comment: I build the DOM tree node by node, so there's no input document. I've checked the structure by some code. Yes, it's good.

Comment: Maybe it is a character encoding issue, where a 0 byte terminates the string. Just make sure your QByteArray does not have a 0 byte at position 256.